# Getting illegal_argument_exception when trying to create index with mapping

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm on elasticsearch 6.6.0 and I'm trying to create and index it fails with an illegal_argument_exception :

```
[root_cause] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [type] => illegal_argument_exception
                            [reason] => unknown setting [index.mappings.place.properties.address.fields.city.fields.de.analyzer] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings
                        )

                )

            [type] => illegal_argument_exception
            [reason] => unknown setting [index.mappings.place.properties.address.fields.city.fields.de.analyzer] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings
            [suppressed] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [type] => illegal_argument_exception
                            [reason] => unknown setting [index.mappings.place.properties.address.fields.city.fields.de.type] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings
                        )...
```

My mapping : http://myjson.com/1559qq

At this point I don't know what am I doing wrong. According to the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/multi-fields.html)  I should be able to create my index with fields containing other properties.

**[edit]** 
So I had multiple problems :

- wrong placement of closing curly brace on settings as pointed by everyone
- string is not longer a type and should be replaced by text or keyword as pointed by @IanGabes
- text + not_analyzed has to be replaced by keyword
- using a keyword (type) as the name of a field
- wrong placement of closing curly brace on address

Thank you a lot everyone.

Comment: The first problem your mapping has is that it `mapping` is not a sub-object of `settings`, its a sibling. you want: `PUT index {"settings":{...},"mapping":{...}}`. After this, you have some more problems to sort out in your types but at least you will have some new error messages to work with.

Comment: `string` is not a datatype, choose between `text` and `keyword`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your json is wrong, your mapping is inside `settings` and elastic thinks that your `field mappings` are `index mapping settings`, as you can see on the error message:

```
unknown setting [index.mappings.place.properties.address.fields.city.fields.de.type]
```

You need to close the curly bracket for the `settings` like the one below.

```
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "number_of_shards": 1,
      "number_of_replicas": 1
     }
    },
    "mappings": {
      "place": {
        "properties": {
          ...
```